# How to only update specific fields in Entity Framework (Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing an application which is pulling data from an external API and storing this into my SQL Server database using Entity Framework. I pull data from this API every day so if a row already exists the record will be updated, otherwise a new record will be created. This is done by checking for the Id.

Now the problem I'm having is that I only want EF to update the `BranchId` and `CustomerNameTopdesk`. The `CustomerNamePRTG` value is added into the database by myself by hand. So right now when the record is updated it's set back to NULL and my manually inserted values will be lost.

**Before Updating**

[image]

**After Updating**

[image: After]

The data from the API is deserialized from JSON and stored in the `data` variable as a `List<Customers>.` I'm using the following code to check if a record already exists by Id and updating it, otherwise creating a new one. As you can see it's currently updating the whole `Customer` record including `CustomerNamePRTG` which is NULL

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(apiResponse);

foreach (Customers customer in data)
{
    if (db.Customers.Any(x => x.BranchId == customer.BranchId))
    {
        db.Customers.Update(customer);
    }
    else
    {
        db.Customers.Add(customer);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Customers
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string BranchId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string CustomerNameTopdesk { get; set; }

    public string CustomerNamePRTG { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to update entity returned by the EF.

```cs
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(apiResponse);

foreach (Customers customer in data)
{
    var current = db.Customers.Find(customer.BranchId);
    if (current != null)
    {
        db.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);
    }
    else
    {
        db.Customers.Add(customer);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: So an extra round trip to the db just to update a column? I know I have seen how to do this without querying the object from the db first.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to assign value to single field only.

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(apiResponse);

foreach (Customers customer in data)
{
    var record = db.Customers.Find(customer.BranchId);
    if (record != null)
    {
        record.BranchId = customer.BranchId;
        // as many fields as you need
 
        db.Customers.Update(record );
    }
    else
    {
        db.Customers.Add(customer);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

While some of these answers will *work* all are highly inefficient. Especially in your case where you are individually updating multiple records.

It seems you have disconnected entities so the important thing here is to avoid making a round trip to the db server for each record. These other answers make a trip to the db once to get the entity then a second time to update it. For each record in your list.

Try this:

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(apiResponse);

foreach (Customers customer in data) {
    var current = new db.Customer();
    current.BranchID = customer.BranchID; // Set the identity
    db.Attach(current); // Starts change tracking
    current.CustomerNameTopdesk = customer.CustomerNameTopdesk; // Any props updated after the .Attach() will be automatically tracked as changed.
    current.CustomerNamePRTG = customer.CustomerNamePRTG;
    // Any properties NOT changed after .Attach() WILL NOT be included in the the generated UPDATE statement.
}

db.SaveChanges();
```