# What is the best way to iterate through a C# object so only the modified fields are updated?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please excuse my limited knowledge of Entity Framework/C#. I'm sure there is an easy way to do what I wish to do.

I want to iterate through an object that I received from the database in order to check which fields are different from my update DTO. I wish to do this so only the changed fields are updated in the objFromDb. I am aware that if I only change the fields in the objFromDb  that are modified, EF will only update the changed fields. I'm not sure if this is necessary or if there is a better way to do it.

Here is my update code (works but not the way I want it to) with the individual properties as well as the commented code that I was trying to accomplish.  I don't like hard-coding the individual properties as this will require maintenance in the event that the object is changed.

```
    public T_IFS_EmployeeDTO Update(T_IFS_EmployeeDTO ojbDTO)
    {
        var objFromDb = _db.T_IFS_Employee.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmployeeID == ojbDTO.EmployeeID);

        if (objFromDb != null)
        {
            //foreach (var prop in objFromDb.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance))
            //{
            //    if (prop.GetValue(objFromDb) != prop.GetValue(ojbDTO))
            //    {
            //        objFromDb.prop.GetValue(objFromDb) = prop.GetValue(ojbDTO);
            //    }
            //}
            if (objFromDb.FirstName != ojbDTO.FirstName) objFromDb.FirstName = ojbDTO.FirstName;
            if (objFromDb.LastName != ojbDTO.LastName) objFromDb.LastName = ojbDTO.LastName;
            if (objFromDb.UserName != ojbDTO.UserName) objFromDb.UserName = ojbDTO.UserName;
            if (objFromDb.Password != ojbDTO.Password) objFromDb.Password = ojbDTO.Password;
            if (objFromDb.AccessLevel != ojbDTO.AccessLevel) objFromDb.AccessLevel = ojbDTO.AccessLevel;
            _db.T_IFS_Employee.Update(objFromDb);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return _mapper.Map<T_IFS_Employee, T_IFS_EmployeeDTO>(objFromDb);
        }
        return ojbDTO;
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this but I haven't been able to figure it out.  I do appreciate your time.

-Edit-

I think the following will work but will EF know if a field has not been modified and is it possible that it is as simple as this:

```
       var objFromDb = _db.T_IFS_Employee.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmployeeID == ojbDTO.EmployeeID);
       var objFromCall = _mapper.Map<T_IFS_EmployeeDTO, T_IFS_Employee>(ojbDTO);

        if (objFromDb != null)
        {
            objFromDb = objFromCall;
```

Comment: Check `DbContext.ChangeTracker`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.changetracker?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-changetracker. ChangeTracker should give you that info.

Comment: Thank you for this tip.  I read that article but I'm not sure how I can apply it here. Would the above edit work or will it update all fields even if not changed?

Comment: That will update all properties. I suggest you search the internet for the words. There are good examples there.

Comment: Isn't what you are trying to do already built into Entity Framework? As far as I know, EF will only set the values of modified fields, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65111363/how-to-only-update-specific-fields-in-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework Core will check the values of your entity and check them against a snapshot of what they were like when you loaded them. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/change-tracking/miscellaneous) for the details.

So you should be able to do:

```
var objFromDb = _db.T_IFS_Employee.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmployeeID == ojbDTO.EmployeeID);
if (objFromDb != null)
{
    _mapper.Map<T_IFS_EmployeeDTO, T_IFS_Employee>(ojbDTO, objFromDb);
    //This overload of .Map sets properties in an existing object, as 
    //opposed to creating a new one
}
```

This will overwrite all properties in `objFromDb` with values from `objDTO`, But only the ones that are different will be written to the database when you call `SaveChanges()`.

Setting `objFromDb` to `objFromCall` will overwrite your reference from the database and this won't be tracked at all.

And there's no need to call `.Update()` if you received the object from the DbContext and you haven't disabled change tracking.

Comment: This worked perfectly and your explanation made it quite clear. Thanks!!